# What does dy or dx mean outside the context of a derivative or integral?

Tags: calculus

This is a snippet from a set of notes on exact differential equations:

[Separable variables, linear, and exact equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duepO.png)

What does a $dx$ or $dy$ mean in isolation? I understand in the case of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ or $\int f(x)dx$, but on their own, what is the formal definition? What is the intuition behind an infinitesimally small change in x (or y) being multiplied by a function?

Comment: If you ask differential geometers, they'll say it represents a differential form, but that's mostly notational convenience for things they want to do with them. It does not mean anything in the context of calculus itself. It's an abuse of notation that I don't think really adds anything, but we're somehow committed to it.

Comment: $dx$ and $dy$ are the linear functions $dx, dy:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ with $dx(a,b)=a$ and $dy(a,b)=b$. They do have meaning, and they are not just notation.

Comment: I view it as an infinitely small change in the variable that corresponds to infinitely small changes in whatever the "ultimate" independent variable is.  You can usually view most relations as being dependent on some other value, whether or not it is represented in a function - let us call it $q$.  Then, let $dq = \epsilon$, a hyperreal infinitesimal.  $dx$ is the change in $x$ when the change in $q$ is $\epsilon$.  See https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.07958

Answer (score 0):

First it helps to understand the total derivative. As a concrete example, consider the paraboloid
$$z = x^2 + 2y^2.$$
If we have a curve $\gamma(t) = [\gamma_x(t), \gamma_y(t),\gamma_z(t)]$ that lies on the paraboloid, we know that for every value of $t$, the curve's coordinates must satisfy the paraboloid equation:
$$\gamma_z(t) = \gamma_x(t)^2 + 2\gamma_y(t)^2.\qquad(\dagger)$$
But we can also say something about the *derivative* of the curve, since no matter how the curve twists and turns on the surface of the paraboloid, it's not free to move off of the surface. We can derive an equation that relates the derivatives of the coordinates of $\gamma$ by differentiating ($\dagger$) with respect to $t$:
$$\frac{\partial \gamma_z}{\partial t}(t) = 2\gamma_x(t)\frac{\partial \gamma_x}{\partial t}(t) + 4\gamma_y(t)\frac{\partial \gamma_y}{\partial t}(t).$$
The idea of the total derivative is that a similar relation must hold for *any* curve on the surface passing through any point. The total derivative encodes this generic relationship between points on the paraboloid and directions tangent to the paraboloid:
$$dz = 2x\,dx + 2y\,dy\qquad(\star)$$
which should be read as: for any arbitrary point $(x,y,z)$ on the paraboloid and vector $(dx,dy,dz)$ tangent to the paraboloid at $(x,y,z)$, the point-vector combination must satisfy equation ($\star$). As Cameron points out in the comments, different authors might write ($\star$) using different notation, and alternatively there are approaches to making the notation in ($\star$) rigorous as-written. But the *common idea* behind notation like $dx$ is that it represents an infinitesimal first-order change (tangent vector) on a curve/surface/other object.

---

Now when $dx$ and $dy$ show up in differential equations as in your linked image, or as in the example
$$x\,dx+y\,dy = 0,$$
the relation on points and tangents is given, but not the curve itself. You should think of the above equation as asking, "find a curve in the plane so that for every point $(x,y)$ on the curve and every tangent vector $(dx,dy)$ to that curve, $x\,dx+y\,dy = 0$." (There might be many solutions (for this example, any circle centered at the origin is a solution; as is any union of multiple such circles) and boundary conditions might pin a unique one down, or you might try to parameterize all possible solutions.) Making this question rigorous requires quite a bit of care that's usually glossed over in physics and engineering applications where these types of equations are common: are you only allowed to look for *smooth* curves? What is "smooth"? And if not, how can you tell which vectors are tangent vectors? The rabbit-hole goes deep.